# Why the child state is not updated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is Parent.js source code:

```
import React,{useState} from "react";
import Child from "./Child";
export default function Parent(){
   const[count,setCount]=useState(0);
   return <Child count={count} setCount={setCount}/>
}
```

the Child.js source code:

```
import React,{useReducer} from "react";
let reducer = (state, action) => {
  let result = { ...state };
  return result;
}
export default function Child({count,setCount}){
  console.log("hi");
  const[text,setText]=useReducer(reducer,count);
  return <>{text}<button onClick={()=>{setCount(count+1)}}>Go</button></>
}
```

My problem is why the variable "text" in Child.js is not updated. at the same time, the variable "count" in Child.js can be updated.

Comment: `text` doesn't change because you don't ever call `setText`. Passing `count` into `useReducer(reducer, count)` just sets the *initial* value of `text`. It will not change it over time.

Comment: when the parent state variable is updated, is a new child component created?

Comment: No, react will just update the props of the existing child.

Comment: Is there a reason you're copying from props into a local state? Can you not use the prop directly? eg, `return <>{count}` instead of `return <>{text}`?

Comment: I am creating a date picker component, assume the child component is the datepicker,in case the parent does not provide on change event handler I want to ensure the date picker can update itself.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see you are calling setText anywhere. Pair in mind that your reducer is just returning a copy of the state.

You have to call setText every time you want it changed just like what you did with setCount

Something like

```
<button
        onClick={() => {
     
          setText(count +1);
          setCount(count + 1);
        }}
```

Comment: How about add the following code in the Child.js:

useEffect(()=>{

setText(count);
},[count])

Comment: It is also a valid approach. This can be extremely useful if target is to always keep text in sync with count

Comment: I can't update my answer with your comment. It's not ethical. You may want to post another answer with your idea